# Pseudo class selectors same values

Tags: css, sass, pseudo-element

I'm using pseudo selectors for my hover and active classes. In this case the color for the hover and active is the same. The way to do it would be like this:

```
a {
  color: #0090B2;
  &:hover {
    color: #FF7A00;
  }
  &.active {
    color: #FF7A00;
  }
}
```

but I would like to not repeat the same attributes, I'm looking for something like this, of course that doesn't work but you get the idea what I wanna do. How would be the right way to do it?. Should I just use a mixin?

```
a {
  color: #0090B2;
  &:hover, &.active {
    color: #FF7A00;
  }
}
```

Comment: I want this result: a {
  color: #0090B2;
}
a:hover {
  color: #FF7A00;
}
a.active {
  color: #FF7A00;
}

Comment: did you mean `a:active` (rather than `a.active`)? `a.active` isn't a pseudo-class. Either way, in CSS, `sel1, sel2 { rules }` is exactly equivalent to `sel1 { rules } ; sel2 { rules }`, so whatever problem you have is not the use of one rule for two different selectors.

Comment: You said "[...] of course that doesn't work...", but it works. Where is your problem with that code? I don't understand, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

## Option 1

I don't understand what is wrong with your way, it's work for me:

```
a {
  color: #0090B2;
  &:hover, &.active {
    color: #FF7A00;
  }
}
```

Which will give you:

```
a {
  color: #00acc1;
}
a:hover, a.active {
  color: #0f9d58;
}
```

## Option 2

```
a {
  color : #00acc1;;

  &:hover {
    @extend %active_link;
  }

  &.active {
    @extend %active_link;
  }
}

%active_link {
  color: #0f9d58;
}
```

Same results as before.
But, here you can do things like:

```
a {
  color : #00acc1;;

  &:hover {
    @extend %active_link;
    content: "AAA";
  }

  &.active {
    @extend %active_link;
    content: "BBB";
  }
}

%active_link {
  color: #0f9d58;
}
```

and get:

```
a {
  color: #00acc1;
}
a:hover {
  content: "AAA";
}
a.active {
  content: "BBB";
}

a:hover, a.active {
  color: #0f9d58;
}
```